# Some album art messed up iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

I bought some music from the itunes Store, I noticed yesterday when I did the usual sync to my iPod Touch it uploaded the wrong album art for some of the records, not sure how many, I havent' gone though the whole playllist. Why is that? and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What happens is you force it to get album art? Right-click on album, or song, and select "Get Album Artwork".

Comment: Good idea, I did it and synced but the changed artwork only shown in the ipod not in itunes.

Comment: You might need to remove those tracks, sync, re-add, sync. Chances are it won't check if artwork changed if nothing else in the track did.